# PHPUnit "Unknown option "--configuration" Process finished with exit code 1" in PhpStorm

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, phpstorm

I am able to execute unit tests in the CLI using the following command:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/bin/php /Users/USERNAME/PhpstormProjects/PROJECT_FOLDER/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit /Users/USERNAME/PhpstormProjects/PROJECT_FOLDER/tests
```

However, i want to fire the tests from inside PhpStorm, but the IDE is automatically adding parameters to the executing command which causes an instant execute fail:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/bin/php /Users/USERNAME/PhpstormProjects/PROJECT_FOLDER/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /Users/USERNAME/PhpstormProjects/PROJECT_FOLDER/phpunit.xml /Users/USERNAME/PhpstormProjects/PROJECT_FOLDER/tests --teamcity
Testing started at 11:51 ...
PHPUnit 9.5.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Unknown option "--configuration"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When i disable the "Default configuration file" checkbox in Preferences > PHP > Test Frameworks > {current project config} - it says:

```
Unknown option "--no-configuration"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is there a way to disable the configuration parameter at all? I'm pretty new to unit tests and i don't even know which purpose this configuration file would even has...

I hope someone can help me - thanks in advance !!

Comment: TBH -- no ideas. I'm on Windows and it works OK here: `E:\Projects\php\php80\php.exe E:/Projects/web/PROJECT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration E:\Projects\web\PROJECT\phpunit.xml --teamcity` 
Testing started at 12:27 ...
PHPUnit 9.5.11 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Time: 00:01.690, Memory: 22.00 MB

OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Does your `PROJECT_FOLDER` (or any other part of the path) has any space symbols in it? Or any symbols that are not alpha-numeric (`.-_` and some other standard symbols are also OK)?

Comment: For me both `--configuration` and `--no-configuration` are working perfectly fine: PhpStorm 2021.3.1 on Windows 10; PHP 8.0 x64 NTS; PHPUnit 9.5.11; standard Laravel 8 app.

Comment: @MyNameIsLinuxx I am assuming you have an issue with your `phpunit`, you should be using `composer`, right? `--configuration` and `--no-configuration` is fine, what happens if you copy the command the IDE is trying to execute and you run it manually?